# Request interpreted as GET instead of POST in Production ENV [NGINX] [Express] [Node]

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, express-router

I have an express API I built to my production environment. When I call a particular endpoint to POST a new object, I get a response as if I were making a GET request. If I call my development environment url, it works fine. Any ideas on what could be causing the issue?

My Routes

```js
// trivia routes
router.post('/trivia', trivia.create);
router.get(
  '/trivia/:slug/start-round/:round',
  trivia.startRound,
  sms.startRound
);
router.get('/trivia/:slug/restart-round/:round', trivia.restartRound);
router.get('/trivia/:slug/end-round/:round', trivia.endRound);
router.get('/trivia/:slug/next-question', trivia.nextQuestion);
router.get('/trivia/:slug/prev-question', trivia.prevQuestion);
router.get('/trivia/:slug/validate', trivia.validate);
router.get('/trivia/:slug', trivia.one);
router.get('/trivia', function (req, res) {
  res.status(400).json({ message: `looks like getting trivia with no slug` });
});
```

I added the last one to try to debug and confirm it was routing to a GET.

///  EDIT  ///

It sounds like the issue is that the request is getting redirected via NGINX. I have the location setup as this:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

How should I modify this setup to not change the request from a POST to a GET, or is there no way around it if I'm using NGINX as a proxy?

Comment: How are you _"calling"_ these endpoints? Do you have any URL rewriting or reverse proxies in front of your Express API in production?

Comment: Sounds like the request is getting redirected

Comment: I suppose it is getting redirected as I'm using Nginx for the web server and forwarding to the port where the node app is running. Any advice on resolving that?